# TensorFlow: How to run timeline / trace? AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'RunSettings'

Tags: python, google-chrome, tensorflow, trace, timeline

apparently, with a recent update to tensorflow, the option of running a trace / timeline / or whatever it's called has disappeared. The following code used to create a .json file that allowed me to see a detailed timeline of the code, using Chrome:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline

run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunSettings.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
sess.run([Network.update], feed_dict = input_dict, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)
tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
with open('trace_file.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(ctf)
```

However, now I'm getting the error

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'RunSettings'
```

Has that function been implemented in another way? I have no idea what the documentation is trying to tell me:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RunOptions

> Class RunOptions
>   Defined in tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto.

This directs me to a github repo and I have no idea how that would be helpful.

TLDR; How do I run the timeline / tracer with the current version of tf (1.4.1)?

Comment: should be `run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)`, maybe just a typo.

Comment: Jesus Christ. Thank you. Don't know how this happened. Sorry.